# Cypher only return nodes where connected nodes don't contain a substring on a property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I can't quite figure out the syntax on something in Cypher. I want to return papers only where none of the authors work at a certain place.

Something like this

```
MATCH (p:Paper)<-[:AUTHOR_OF]-(authors)
WHERE NOT (p)<-[:AUTHOR_OF]-(authors).institute CONTAINS "SomeInstituteName"
RETURN p, authors
```

Unfortunately this throws an error.

I also tried this:

```
MATCH (p:Paper)<-[:AUTHOR_OF]-(authors)
WHERE NOT authors.institute CONTAINS "SomeInstituteName"
RETURN p, authors
```

This doesn't work either as it just returns all the papers and filters out authors that work at some institute. I'd like to only return papers where not even one author works at 'SomeInstituteName'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
MATCH (p:Paper)<-[:AUTHOR_OF]-(a:Author)
WITH p, collect(a) AS authors
WHERE NONE(x IN authors WHERE x.institute CONTAINS "SomeInstituteName")
RETURN p, authors
```